# Help with Python setup.py with multiple folders

Tags: python, setup.py

I'm trying to build my program on the OBS. Could you please tell me what the setup.py should look like to create a folder structure, for example if I have this:

```
../MyProgram
COPYING
README
mainscript.pyw
/applications
    /app1
        /icons
            pic1.png
        app1.py
    /app2
        /icons
            pic2.png
        /scripts
            script1.py
            script2.py
        app2.py
```

etc.

I read the Python Docs, played with 'package_dir', 'packages' but the OBS still gives me errors it can't find the icon files. I guess the setup script doesn't create them. And when I tried to build an rpm locally, it gave me the same error. When I looked in the BUILD folder, there was no folder 'applications' created and nothing below it.

Will really appreciate your help. Please provide an example. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to add in your MANIFEST.in the following line :

```
recursive-include applications *.png
```

to include all the icons.

To embed your python files, try to explicitly declare your packages like this :

```
setup(
   packages=[
      "applications",
      "applications.app1",
      "applications.app2",
      "applications.app2.scripts",
   ],
   data_files=[    # declare the list of  data_files (destination directory, (data files))
      ("applications/app1/icons", ("applications/app1/icons/pic1.png",)),
      ("applications/app2/icons", ("applications/app2/icons/pic2.png",)),
   ]
   .... # your other setup options (name, version...)
)
```

but you'll have to put __init__.py files under each directory to allow python to take them as packages.

Comment: why not use graft?

Answer (score 0):

I found help here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils/Tutorial

You create a Manifest.in file for the files you like to include:

```
recursive-include applications/app1/icons *.png
recursive-include applications/app2/icons *.png
```